# Problem buliding old project with flutter 2.0.0

Tags: flutter, dart-null-safety

After upgrading to flutter 2.0.0 I can't build the app anymore. this is the output. My problem is I have heavy usage of libraries and a lot of them are not null safe and I can't upgrade all of my dependencies to null safe mode. Does anyone have any suggestions on this?

```
Try calling using ?. instead.
    ).replaceFirst(r'$remainingCount', formatDecimal(remainingCount));
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../flutter/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/extended_image-1.6.0/lib/src/extended_image.dart:785:44: Error: No named parameter with the name 'nullOk'.
    _invertColors = MediaQuery.of(context, nullOk: true)?.invertColors ??
                                           ^^^^^^
../../flutter/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/media_query.dart:818:25: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
  static MediaQueryData of(BuildContext context) {

                        ^^
../../flutter/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_svg-0.18.1/lib/src/picture_provider.dart:50:59: Error: No named parameter with the name 'nullOk'.
        context != null ? Localizations.localeOf(context, nullOk: true) : null,
                                                          ^^^^^^
../../flutter/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/localizations.dart:413:17: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
  static Locale localeOf(BuildContext context) {

                ^^^^^^^^
```

update 1: After updating to flutter 2.0.1 and `flutter pub cache repair` and `flutter clean`. and running with flag `flutter run --no-sound-null-safety`. Still, no chance to run the app and this is the output.

```
../../flutter/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_neumorphic-3.0.3/lib/src/widget/app_bar.dart:147:57: Error: No named parameter with the name 'nullOk'.
    final ScaffoldState scaffold = Scaffold.of(context, nullOk: true);
                                                        ^^^^^^
../../flutter/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/scaffold.dart:1944:24: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
  static ScaffoldState of(BuildContext context) {
                       ^^
../../flutter/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_svg-0.19.1/lib/src/picture_provider.dart:52:59: Error: No named parameter with the name 'nullOk'.     
        context != null ? Localizations.localeOf(context, nullOk: true) : null,
                                                          ^^^^^^
../../flutter/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/localizations.dart:413:17: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
  static Locale localeOf(BuildContext context) {
                ^^^^^^^^


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'D:\Documents\flutter\flutter\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 991

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command 'D:\Documents\flutter\flutter\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 26s
```

Update 2: Here is an output of `flutter doctor`

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.0.1, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19042.804], locale en-US)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[√] Visual Studio - develop for Windows (Visual Studio Community 2019 16.8.4)   
[√] Android Studio (version 4.1.0)
[√] IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (version 2020.3)
[√] VS Code (version 1.54.1)
[√] Connected device (4 available)

• No issues found!
```

Comment: did it get solved?

Comment: Nope, I'm using flutter 1.22.6, for now, to build my projects until all of the dependencies migrate to null safety then see if the new flutter works.

Comment: same here, I too switched to 1.22

Comment: any news on this issue ?

Comment: No, unfortunately, I'm still using 1.22.6 version of flutter due to some packages of my project that are not still migrated to null safety.

Answer (score 1):

```
flutter clean
```

and

```
flutter pub get
```

should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can still using Flutter 2.0 with ignoring the null safety migration. Set this sdk constraint version in your `pubspec.yaml`

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"
```

Comment: Yes I know, I never updated the dart SDK of my project. Still I cannot build

Comment: I had the same problem and solved it by setting the SDK to ">=2.7.0 <=2.12.2"